# If-Else Statement isn't executing correctly

Tags: java

This is my code, by the way I'm not asking for a free fix I'm looking for someone to help me and explain my error. Thanks in advance!

```
    * Psuedocode: 
 * 1. Ask the user if they want to enter a number or if they want the computer to select a random number. 
 * 2. Based on the user selection, Ask the user for a number or generate a random number. 
 * 3. Read the number from the user (Skip the step if a random number is generated)
 * 4. Check if the number is 1 digit or 2 digit or 3 digit or 4 digit
 * 5. if it is 1 digit then check if the cube of number equals the number
 * 6. else if it is 2 digit, get the cube of first and second digits and then sum them up and check if the number is equal to the sum.
 * 7. else if it is 3 digit, get the cube of first, second and third digits and then sum them up andcheck if the number is equal to the sum.
 * 8. if it is 4 digit, get the cube of first, second, third and fourth digits and then sum them up andcheck if the number is equal to the sum.
 * 9. else tell the user that the number they have entered is not within 9999
 * 10. Print a closing message saying if the number is an Armstrong number or not. 
 * 11. Print a goodbye statement.
```

*/

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.Random;

    public class ArmstrongNumber {

       public static boolean Armstrong(int input) {
           String inputString = input + "";
       int numberOfDigits = inputString.length();
       int copyOfInput = input;
       int sum = 0;

       while (copyOfInput != 0) {
           int lastDigit = copyOfInput % 10;
           sum = sum + (int) Math.pow(lastDigit, numberOfDigits);
           copyOfInput = copyOfInput / 10;
       }
       if (sum == input) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

           System.out.print("Enter a number to check if it is an Armstrong number or generate a random number: ");
       int inputNumber = scanner.nextInt();
       int choice = 0;
       Random rand = new Random();
       if(choice == 1)
       {
                     inputNumber = scanner.nextInt();
       }
       else if(choice == 2)
       {
                     inputNumber =  rand.nextInt(9999) + 1; ;//generate a random number between 1 and 9999
       }





       boolean result = Armstrong(inputNumber);
       if (result) {
           System.out.println("");
           System.out.println(inputNumber + " is an Armstrong number");
       } else {
           System.out.println("");
           System.out.println(inputNumber + " is not an Armstrong number");

       }
       System.out.println("");
       System.out.println("Thanks for using my code. Goodbye");
   }
}
```

The random generator method for my choices is not working. It is displaying only 1 and 2 as either armstrong number or not armstrong number but not generating a random number for choice 2

Comment: `int choice = 0` followed by `if(choice == 1)` ... well, that'll never be true ... followed by `else if(choice == 2)` ... nope, never true either.

Comment: When I uninitialize choice then there is a compiler error in the if else statement about it being uninitialized.

Comment: basically `choice` is not being assigned from your input before you test its value.

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
   int choice = 0;
   Random rand = new Random();
   // you need to assign something to choice before the next line
   // maybe choice = rand.nextInt (); ?
   if(choice == 1)
```